# Changing hash change to use slash instead

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, url, hashchange

I am currently using hashchange along with some jquery code to switch between links on my page : bradleyhobbs.com/bodyevolution

However, Instead of the webpage showing as localhost/#home or localhost/#membership, I want the url to show localhost/home or localhost/membership. I want it to work the same way as using hashchange i just don't want to show the hash in the browser url.

You can check out the site or see this code i'm using for hashchange:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).hashchange(function(){
var hash = location.hash;
if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "home") {
            $("#main").show();
            $("#membership").hide();
            $("#contact").hide();
            $("#main_template").hide();
        }
          else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "memberships") {
            $("#main").hide();
            $("#contact").hide();
            $("#membership").show();
            $("#main_template").show();
        }
                  else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "contact") { 
            $("#contact").show();
            $("#main_template").show();
            $("#main").hide();
            $("#membership").hide();
        }
$('#list a').each(function(){
var that = $(this);
that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
});
})
$(window).hashchange();
});
```

I know i probably need to use .htaccess to edit the url but i don't know where to begin.

Comment: [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Comment: If you want wide browser support, this isn't possible yet.

Comment: How would I use history.js with what i'm trying to accomplish?